# Finding shortest paths to all desired points in a graph

Tags: graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I was asked the following question in an interview

> You are given a 4 X 4 grid. Some locations on the grid contain
>   treasure. Your task is the visit all the locations that contain the
>   treasure and collect it. You are allowed to move on the four adjacent
>   cells (up, down, left, right). Each movement and the action of
>   "treasure collection" is of a single unit cost. You need to traverse
>   the entire grid, and collect all the treasure on the grid, minimizing
>   the cost taken.

If I can recall properly, here is a sample graph that was given:

```
U..X
..X.
X..X
..X.
```

Where, U is my current position and X marks the position of the treasure.

The solution that I presented was to use breadth first search traversing the graph and "collecting the treasure" while doing so. However, the interviewer insisted that there was a better way to minimize the cost. I hope you could help me in figuring it out.

Comment: If "You need to traverse the entire grid", just take a pregenerated Hamiltonian path (one of three, based on your initial position) and pick up the treasures as you got.

Comment: Are you sure "You need to traverse the entire grid", not just the treasure boxes?

Comment: I mean that the requirement was to traverse through all the treasure boxes, not the entire grid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have recognized that this is a Traveling Salesman Problem in a small disguise. Using breadth-first, you can determine the shortest way between the different vertices you have to visit which gives you a derived graph containing just those ways as weighted edges between the vertices. From then on, it's a classic TSP.

Answer (score 3):

BFS alone is not going to solve it for you, because you cannot move in all directions at the same time. It is not a single-source shortest path problem, because once you collect the treasure, you start your path to the next one from your current spot, not from the original spot.

The time that it takes to collect all treasure depends on the order in which you visit the boxes with `X`. Since there are only five of them, you can try all 120 orderings, compute the cost, and pick the best one.

Note that if the order is fixed, the solution is trivial: you add up [manhattan distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) between the cells in order, and pick the smallest result.

Comment: What makes you sure there are only 5 boxes?

Comment: @JanDvorak The picture from the post :)

Comment: I don't think that counts ;-)